# HTML5 Canvas not resizing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to resize my html5 canvas to be the same size as the page but for some reason, the javascript isn't changing its size.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

$(window).resize(function() {
  canvas.width = $(window).width();
  canvas.height = $(window).height();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
<!-- more html -->
```

The canvas remains 500px no matter what I do, please help.

Comment: You are setting `width` and `height` of the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` instead of the canvas

Comment: Have you tried setting with and height of the canvas itself instead of its 2d context?

Comment: How can I do this? Also why the downvote?

Comment: Please read a tutorial about the subject (and think about what `.getContext('2d')` does).

Comment: Wow I feel like an idiot thanks all

Comment: The typical way this is handled in tutorials is a variable called `canvas` references the `HTMLCanvasElement` (the actual canvas element), while `ctx` references the `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, aka `canvas.getContext("2d")`. Of course you are free to name your variables whatever you want, but i think the name of the variable here is partly to blame for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        var h = $(window).height();
        $('#canvas').width(w);
        $('#canvas').height(h);
   });

   $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        var h = $(window).height();
        $('#canvas').width(w);
        $('#canvas').height(h);
   });
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  /* for testing */
  background: #CFF000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: This worked but it made what I was drawing on the canvas very pixilated... Is there a way to resize the canvas without this effect?

Comment: This a) doesn't answer why the OP's code fails b) is a terrible solution because as OP already noticed, setting canvas size with css doesn't change the underlying resolution but stretches the result into place.